# Delaying load level in c# unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created some code that is meant to load my next level 20 seconds after the user has completed it, however i get an error "object reference is required to access a static function" however i need the function to be static to be able to call it when my helicopter doors open and the user can get in the helicopter. Can anyone help?

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {


    static bool _hasPlayerWon = false;

    public static bool HasPlayerWon {get{return _hasPlayerWon;}}

    Health _playerHealth;




    public static void WinPlayer()
    {

        _hasPlayerWon = true;
        Invoke("loadSplash",20.0f);

    }


    void loadSplash ()
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("splash1");

    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a field that holds a reference to the GameManager and call a Coroutine using that method that triggers the load.

Something like this:

```
static private GameManager instance;

void Awake()
{
    instance = this;
}

public static void WinPlayer()
{
    _hasPlayerWon = true;
    instance.LoadLevel();
}

private void LoadLevel()
{
  StartCoroutine( LoadCo() );
}

private IEnumerator LoadCo()
{
  yield return new WaitForSeconds( 20.0 );

  Application.LoadLevel("splash1");
}
```